# Identify Increasing ID column by factor of 1

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Let`s say i have a column like this:

```
ID
1
2
4
5
6
11
12
15
16
18
19
20
25
31
```

i want to be able to query only those columns where there ID increases by 1 and only if it occur X times in a rows (the X is a variable that needs to be able to be changed )
so from the above column my SQL should return this:

```
ID
4
5
6
18
19
20
```

only the ID`s that increases by 1 and happens 3 times in a row.
i am using ORACLE 11g

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hm, try something like this:

```
Select t1.id, t2.id, t3.id from table as t1
inner join table as t2 on t1.id = (t2.id + 1)
inner join table as t3 on t2.id = (t3.id + 1)
```

X would be the number of joins

For a dynamically sql-query depending on x you could build something like this:

```
SET @SQLQuery1 = 'Select t0.id ';
SET @SQLQuery2 = '';
x=10;

while x > 0
begin
@SQLQuery1+=',t'+x+'.id';
@SQLQuery2+='inner join table as t'+x+' on t1.id = (t' + x + '.id + x)';
x= x-1;
end
@SQLQuery1 = @SQLQuery1+ 'from table as t0 ' + @SQLQuery2;
EXECUTE(@SQLQuery1);
```

Can not test this right now, so maybe you must modify this a bit till it works, i hope this works in your environment, i dont use oracle 11g

Comment: the X should be something i can send as variable into the Query.

Comment: Ok, i edited my post, but i guess you have to do some research and changing to make this work for you, because i cant test it right now. But i showed you one possible way to solve this. Maybe somebody will post a better solution later...